# How do I take this array and transform it to a collection in F#?

Tags: f#

I am looking to take this array which is an output from Excel provider and create a record from this. My code is shown below:

```
open FSharp.Interop.Excel
type Data = {
    Time: string
    Pressure: string
    Force: string
    Appshear: string
    Stress: string
    Appvisc: string
    Shear: string
    Viscosity: string
    Position: string
    Temperature: string
    Velocity: string
    Fgamr: string
    M: string
    }
type TheFile = ExcelFile<"***********.xls","Data",Range = "A3">
let file2 = TheFile()
let rows = file2.Data 
           |> Seq.skip 2
           |> Seq.toArray
```

The output from my code is as follows:

```
val rows : ExcelFile<...>.Row [] =
  [|Row 3
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 4
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 5
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 6
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 7
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 8
        ETA 1 = **
        ETAap 1 = **
        FGamR1 = **
        Fst1 = **
        GAM 1 = **
        GAMap 1 = **
        M1 = **
        P1 = **
        Position = **
        TAU 1 = **
        TAUap 1 = **
        TS1 = **
        TS2 = **
        TS3 = **
        Time = **
        V = **;
    Row 9
        ETA 1 =
        ETAap 1 =
        FGamR1 =
        Fst1 =
        GAM 1 =
        GAMap 1 =
        M1 =
        P1 =
        Position =
        TAU 1 =
        TAUap 1 =
        TS1 =
        TS2 =
        TS3 =
        Time =
        V = |]
```

My goal is to create a record with all of the data in it. I am able to call each of the variables by indexing them one at a time but am not loop through all of the rows. How would I do this? An example of what I can do is shown below.

```
let time = rows.[0].GetValue "Time"|> string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` function to transform your excel rows to records.

Just add another pipe:

```
|> Array.map (fun row ->
    { Time = row.GetValue "Time" |> string
      Pressure = ...
      Force = ...
      ... })
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question from the comments — I would filter out empty rows before transforming them to records. I've found no public member to access the columns, so one idea could be to define a list of columns by yourself:

```
let columns =
    [ "Time"; "..."; "..." ]

let isEmptyRow (row: TheFile.Row) =
    columns
    |> List.map (row.GetValue >> string) // Assuming that all defined columns are strings
    |> List.forall ((=) "")

let rows =
    file.Data
    |> Seq.filter (not << isEmptyRow)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! How would I remove empty records from an entry in f#. For example: if there was a just empty strings ' ' for every field value

Comment: @Canadian_Hombre I've edited my answer to show you one of many ways to solve this problem.